# Does meta viewport override media queries or vice versa

Tags: css, media-queries, viewport

If you use a meta viewport tag as below to tell a mobile browser to scale its content as if its being viewed on a 1200px wide display (the actual width of the browser in question is 500px)

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200px;" />
```

and then also use a media query like

```
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 1200px) { /* NEW CSS */ }
```

Which would get used? As with out the `viewport` tag the media query = true, so the new css should be used, but the `viewport` is saying the device is `1200px`.

**NOTE:** im using `max-width` which equates to the browser window width, rather than `max-device-width` which equates to the device width